# .NET project with EF Core throws ObjectDisposedException on one particular page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, memorycache

The ASP.NET Core project with Entity Framework is erroring out when I am trying to access a page. I tried googling the error and my method is using `async Task` and not void and I have set the `sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();` on `AddDbContextPool`. But still when we are accessing the page it still errors out saying

> ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

On the `Index()` of the page I am doing the caching to

```
 public class CustomersController : Controller
 {
     private readonly SurplusMouseContext _context;
     private readonly IMemoryCache memoryCache;

     public CustomersController(SurplusMouseContext context, IMemoryCache _memoryCache)
     {
         _context = context;
         memoryCache = _memoryCache;
     } 

     // GET: Customers
     public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString,
                                            int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
     {
         var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

         IQueryable<JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.Setting> settings_data = null;
         IQueryable<JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.HolidayWeek> holidaycheck = null;

         TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
         var todayDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);

         TimeSpan timeNow = TimeSpan.Parse(todayDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

         bool isExist = memoryCache.TryGetValue("HolidayWk", out holidaycheck);

         if (!isExist)
         {
             holidaycheck = (from hc in _context.HolidayWeeks
                             where hc.HolidateDate == todayDt.Date
                             select hc);
             var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

             memoryCache.Set("HolidayWk", holidaycheck, cacheEntryOptions);
         }

         bool isSettingExist = memoryCache.TryGetValue("SMSettings", out settings_data);

         if (!isSettingExist)
         {
            settings_data = (from s in _context.Settings                                
                             select s).Take(1);
            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                     .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

            memoryCache.Set("SMSettings", settings_data, cacheEntryOptions);
         }

         int i = settings_data.Count();

         if (holidaycheck.Count() != 0)
         {
             HolidayWeek viewmodel = new HolidayWeek
                         {
                             Holiday = holidaycheck.First().Holiday.ToUpper()
                         };

             return View("/Views/Customers/AppNotAvailableHoliday.cshtml", viewmodel);
         }
         else if (settings_data.Count() != 0)
         {
             string myCondition = (todayDt.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0, 3)).ToUpper();
             string abc = settings_data.First().OrderDay;

             TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.Parse(settings_data.First().StartTime);
             TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.Parse(settings_data.First().EndTime);

             bool checktime = (timeNow >= start) && (timeNow <= end);

             if ((settings_data.First().OrderDay == myCondition)&&((timeNow>=start) && (timeNow <= end)))
             {
                 ViewData["CustomerParam"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "customer_desc" : "";
                ViewData["LocationParam"] = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) || sortOrder == "location_asc" ? "location_desc" : "location_asc";

                ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;
                ViewData["CurrentSort"] = sortOrder;

                if (searchString != null)
                {
                    pageNumber = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    searchString = currentFilter;
                }

                var cust = from s in _context.Customers
                           select s;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    cust = cust.Where(s => s.Location.Contains(searchString));
                }

                switch (sortOrder)
                {
                    case "location_desc":
                        cust = cust.OrderByDescending(s => s.Location);
                        break;

                    case "location_asc":
                        cust = cust.OrderBy(s => s.Location);
                        break;

                    case "customer_desc":
                        cust = cust.OrderBy(s => s.CustomerNumber);
                        break;

                    default:
                        cust = cust.OrderBy(s => s.Location);
                        break;
                }

                int pageSize = 15;

                return View(await PaginatedList<Customer>.CreateAsync(cust.AsNoTracking(), pageNumber ?? 1, pageSize));
           }
           else
           {
                Setting ss = new Setting
                {
                    OrderDay = settings_data.First().OrderDay,
                    StartTime = settings_data.First().StartTime,
                    EndTime = settings_data.First().EndTime
                };

                return View("/Views/Customers/AppNotAvailableSettings.cshtml", ss);
           }
       }

       return View("/Views/Customers/AppNotAvailableSettings.cshtml");           
    }
```

I am querying two different tables `HolidayWeek` and `Setting` to check if the customer page can be available or not. If the customer pages shouldn't be accessible, I return different views to the users. I am not sure if I am missing anything with caching part.

This error is pretty inconsistent once it appears and then again it fails. Can anyone suggest if I am missing something here?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to cache `IQueryable`, which is delayed execution of the query. It contains reference to `DbContext` which is disposed by container later.

So resolution is simple - materialise objects before caching:

```cs
memoryCache.Set("HolidayWk", await holidaycheck.ToListAsync(), cacheEntryOptions);
```

Same mistake in other places.

Anyway probably you have to change types of your cached entries:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string sortOrder, string searchString,
                                        int? pageNumber, string currentFilter)
{
    var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;

    List<JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.Setting> settings_data = null;
    List<JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.HolidayWeek> holidaycheck = null;

    TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    var todayDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);

    TimeSpan timeNow = TimeSpan.Parse(todayDt.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));

    bool isExist = memoryCache.TryGetValue("HolidayWk", out holidaycheck);

    if (!isExist)
    {
        holidaycheck = await (from hc in _context.HolidayWeeks
                        where hc.HolidateDate == todayDt.Date
                        select hc).ToListAsync();
        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
        .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

        memoryCache.Set("HolidayWk", holidaycheck, cacheEntryOptions);
    }

    bool isSettingExist = memoryCache.TryGetValue("SMSettings", out settings_data);

    if (!isSettingExist)
    {
        settings_data = await (from s in _context.Settings                                
                            select s).Take(1).ToListAsync();
        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                    .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromHours(2));

        memoryCache.Set("SMSettings", settings_data, cacheEntryOptions);
    }
  ...
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with the other mistakes that I have

Comment: `settings_data` also cached as `IQueryable`

Comment: But I cannot change the `await holidaycheck.ToListAsync()` it throws error `'IQueryable<HolidayWeek>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no accessible extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'IQueryable<HolidayWeek>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: How it can be? This is widely used EF Core extension. Probably you have to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Comment: I already have the `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` Can I leave the `IQueryable<JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.HolidayWeek> holidaycheck = null;` as is?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: I had a typo and the `await holidaycheck.ToListAsync()` fix seems to be working.. Can I still use the `IQueryable` as it working or is it recommended to change that to the List as `List<JAXSurplusMouseApp.Models.HolidayWeek>`

Comment: You have to change to List<>, for now you caches lists, so retrieved type should List. What you put is what you get.